# How to manually populate a pandas dataframe using calculated values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have several dataframes (by quarter) and I am calculating values for each quarter and trying to populate a table that has a date variable (quarterly) i.e.

```
date 
12-31-2015
03-31-2016
06-30-2016
...
```

Here, for each quarter, I have a list of top accounts, and I am summing, let's say, the first 100 rows to calculate the holding of the top 100 accounts per quarter.

```
topaccount_2015_12['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum
topaccount_2016_03['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum
...
```

Now, I want to populate the table with the calculated values. I tried,

```
top100 = np.array([topaccount_2015_12['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, 
                   topaccount_2016_03['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2016_06['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2016_09['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2016_12['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum,
                   topaccount_2017_03['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2016_06['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2017_09['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2017_12['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum,
                   topaccount_2018_03['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2016_06['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2018_09['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2018_12['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum,
                   topaccount_2019_03['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2016_06['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2019_09['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2019_12['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum,
                   topaccount_2020_03['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2016_06['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2020_09['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2020_12['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum,
                   topaccount_2021_03['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2016_06['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2021_09['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum, topaccount_2021_12['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum])

wealth['top100'] = top100.tolist()
```

but the result gives a strange array (below).

How do I add only the calculated values to the table as a second column?

[image]

Comment: Change `topaccount_2015_12['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum` to `topaccount_2015_12['balance'].iloc[0:100].sum()`. You need the parantheses to actually call the `sum` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be approaching this in the wrong way. Pandas has functionality for performing this type of group summarization.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve precisely, but you could try something like:

- concatenate all your dataframes, so they share a single date column
- use `pd.Grouper` (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) to group your observations by quarter.
- use `pd.group_by` and `.agg()` to perform some summarization by quarter. This will give you a new data frame with one row per quarter.

Comment: each dataframe is quite big, so concatenating it, i think, will slow down the whole thing, that's why i have separate dataframes.

Comment: I think the advice by @distracted-biologist is pretty good. I recommend you give it a try. Having all data in one dataframe may actually speed up the computations. In addition, it allows you writing complex operations in a very concise way. At the moment, your code contains a lot of repetitions (e.g., you use `iloc` and `sum` multiple times). Once you have all the data in one data frame and in the correct format, it basically becomes a one-liner like `df.groupby('date')['balance'].apply(lambda x: x[:100].sum())`